# Spring Boot login error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring's `PasswordEncoder` to create and update a users password, however, when I update user password, I get an error.

The issue is when I create a new user and use their credentials to log in, it works fine. On the other hand, when I update their password (with PasswordEncoder), the new password generates an invalid username/password error despite the fact that the password does indeed update in the database. Following is the logic for updating password;

```
@PostMapping("/updatepassword")
public String updateUserPassword(UserEntity userEntity, Model model, 
                  @RequestParam(name = "useridpass") Long userIdFromUpdatePass, 
                  @RequestParam(required = false, name = "usernewpass") String newPass) {

    userEntity = userRegisterRepository.findById(userIdFromUpdatePass);
    userEntity.setUserpassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userEntity.getUserpassword()));
    userRegisterRepository.save(userEntity);
    return "redirect:/jobs";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the value to a hash of the already-hashed value in the entity instead of the value from the request.  Specifically, change

```
userEntity.setUserpassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userEntity.getUserpassword()));
```

To

```
userEntity.setUserpassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPass));
```

**EDITED TO ADD**  You may want to throw a null check on `newPass` first too.

Comment: @IssmeilB. if this answer resolved your issue, mark it as the correct answer please.